# Error "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" a la hora de traer datos con un $.get o un $.getJSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Buenas y espero me ayuden con esta problematica que tengo ahora.

Tengo un input que a la hora de escribir en él al usuario le aparece palabras o datos que vienen desde una tabla, esto lo logro con la funcion a continuación.

```
function initializeAutoCompletes() {

        $.getJSON('/admin/projects/memorias_institucionales/source', {
            table: "onomastico"
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(".onomasticos").typeahead({
                source: data
            });
        });

        $.get('/admin/projects/memorias_institucionales/source', {
            table: "onomastico"
        })
             .done(function(response) {
                   console.log(response);
                   //Funcion de prueba, imprime el error
             });

    }
    initializeAutoCompletes();
```

He notado que con la funcion de prueba la cual imprime el error me imprime por consola lo siguiente:

```
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ruta_del_proyecto/controllers/projects.php:396)</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Session.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 675</p>
```

He notado que solo me imprime dicho error si solo hay mas de 62 registros en la tabla "onomasticos", ya cuando pasa de 62 el autocompletar no funciona y al final de imprimir el json (Todos los datos que trae de la tabla) me imprime el error. Por si lo necesitan estoy trabajando en PHP con CodeIgniter y esta es la funcion source de mi controlador:

```
public function source() {
        $table = $_GET['table'];
        $data = $this->adm_model->select_all("description",$table);

        foreach($data as $dataRow)
            $json[] = $dataRow['description'];

        if($json)
            echo json_encode($json);//Aqui es donde da el error segun me indica la linea.
        else
            echo json_encode(array($q." *** (Nuevo $table)"));
    }
```

Y esta es la funcion del modal con la cual traigo los datos:

```
public function select_all($s,$table)
    {
        $this->db->select($s);
        $this->db->from($table);
        $dataResult = $this->db->get();

        return $dataResult->result_array() ? $dataResult->result_array() : -1;
    }
```

**NOTA**: Aunque hayan mas de 62 registros el json trae todos los datos sin importar que pasen de 62 registros pero al final de imprimir el ultimo datos lanza el error que mencione anteriormente.

Comment: Estás usando $.getJSON y $.get en una misma instrucción? Porque esa no es la manera de implementarlo, o usas una o usas otra. En tu código estás enviando las 2 consultas al servidor. Por eso te da el mensaje de `headers already sent`

Comment: @MauricioContreras solamente use la segunda para poder imprimir lo que traía el JSON, en principio solo había una y aun así permanece el error.

Comment: ¿El error te lo lanza en algún registro específico después del 62 o aleatoriamente pasando el registro 62?

Comment: Luego de pasar 62 registros lanza ese error. Si borro uno pues todo funciona como se debe aunque hayan dos consultas al servidor.

Comment: Lo de que 'hayan dos consultas al servidor' está mal. En un mismo procedimiento no deberías hacer más de una petición al servidor. En cuanto al hecho que da el error cuando hay 63 registros o más me indica que hay un problema en los registros. ¿Has probado aislar la consulta y depurar la salida?

Comment: Otra pregunta, ¿qué hace esto?: `$q." *** (Nuevo $table)"`